# How to solve the alignment problem when an enumerate list over two pages?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Assuming \( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = a\) , proof \( \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = a\).
    \par \emph{Hint:}
      \( \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a  \Rightarrow  \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n)^{1/n} = a\)

    \item Proof \( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}) = 0\).
    \par \emph{Hint:}
      \( \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a  \Rightarrow  \lim_{n \to \infty} (a_1 + a_2 +\cdots+ a_n) = a\)
      
    \item Let \(p(n)\) be the number of prime factors of n, proof \( \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{p(n)}{n} = 0\).
    \par 
    \emph{Proof:} \[n = p_1^{s_1} p_2^{s_2} \cdots p_m^{s_m}, \quad m=p(n)\]
    \[m<s_1+s_2+s_3+\cdots+s_m\]
    
    Since 2 is the smallest prime number,
    \[2^{s_1+s_2+s_3+\cdots+s_m}<n\]
    thus,
    \[ s_1+s_2+s_3+\cdots+s_m<\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{2}} \]
    \[ \frac{p(n)}{n} < \frac{\ln{n}}{n \ln{2}} \]
    \item
\end{enumerate}
```

Thank you for solving my problem below!
[image: Thanks!]

Comment: You should share what you have tried so far. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But an MWE is a compilable file starting from `\documentclass[...]{...}` and ending with `\end{documnet}`. For your case, I think the document class you are using is important to know.

Comment: This is my document class \documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be aligned? On what?

Comment: I think you are troubled with the fact that items in even and odd pages don't start from the same margin. But it's the feature of the two side document that you are using.

Comment: @Imran Thx very much!

Comment: @HaosonQ: And if you don't want that, you can use the `oneside` document class option.

Comment: you have not said what your problem is. unrelated to alignment do not use one \[ after another use a multiline display such as `gather`